# OTC Microwave loose when mounting screws are tight

Tags: microwave-oven

After installing a new LG model LMV1764, mounting screws do not pull the unit fully up to the cabinet bottom. Both screws are tight, but the unit is loose with about 3/16" gap. The unit can be easily pushed up tight by hand. I cut an inch off the screws and have the same results. Threads on the screws run right up to the head, so it's not running out of thread. Two engineers cannot find the solution. How about you?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. [Edit] your question to add some.

Comment: Pictures will be nice.  Something seems weird if shorten screws do the same thing.  What do the instructions say?  Screws/bolts pull things tight unless they are too long and hit something hard(steel plate).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the [installation video](https://www.lg.com/us/support/help-library/installation-overtherange-microwave-oven-CT00000303-1426865800201). Based on that, I think you have one of two situations:

- The mounting bracket on the wall was mounted a little lower than it should have been.
- The cabinet has a lip around the bottom so that measuring from the bottom of the cabinet lip to install the mounting bracket results in a gap between the oven and the floor of the cabinet.

In either case, the solution is to add some filler blocks as shown in the video at 3:50.

Comment: That or go to a hardware store and get some shorter bolts of the same size and thread pitch.,

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I think the problem here is that the bolts are tightened when the microwave oven is hanging level. But there is a gap above *part* of the top of the oven so it can be pushed up. Therefore, filler pieces are needed to give a level surface above the microwave oven.

Comment: And shorter screws were already tried, as per the question post.

Comment: I don't see how filler blocks would help here. The solution to the first problem you list is to reset the mounting plate.

Comment: Resetting the mounting plate may not be so easy. Based on the video, it is two toggle bolts + 1 screw into a stud. Move everything 1", no problem. Move it 3/16" and I worry you'll end up with stacked holes that merge together and then don't hold properly. Put it 3/16" (or maybe 1/4") plywood filler and it should be just right.

Comment: I've done a lot of these. There's slop in a toggle bolt hole that may suffice, but new holes can be punched about anywhere if the plethora of options don't allow better screw locations. It's not a concern.